# Matplotlib Histogram and a List

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

My problem is very simple.

I got a list of times and a list of numbers.

```
listTimes = [2103, 2103, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108, 2108]
listNumbers = [2, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

I want to make a histogram showing that at 21:03 the number 2 popped up twice.
That same histogram should say that at 21:04 the number 4 popped up once and number 7 twice.

Is this possible?

Bye.

Comment: Did you mean to have listTimes and listNumbers be the same length?

Comment: What would you expect with`listTimes = [2103, 2103, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108, 2108]`
and `listNumbers = [2, 3, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5]`?

Comment: @ SEClark: Yes they both have the same length. 
@ Cedric H: When I plot it using a plt.bar it only gives me the highest number at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [two-dimensional histogram](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) plot:

```
plt.hexbin(listTimes, listNumbers)
```

Comment: I'll try this once I get home. Thanks!